# Counter-example to this property in euclidean geometry?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, examples-counterexamples

I have to prove that this property is false, finding a counter-example.

> If $\widehat{A}=\widehat{C}=90^{\circ}$ then the convex quadrilateral $ABCD$ is a rectangle.

I can't find any counter-example with this measure of angle because this property seems to be true. I took a right trapezoid $ABCD$ but it's $\widehat{A}=\widehat{D}=90^{\circ}$...

I'm probably blind...

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take two right angles as follows, rotate one to some small angle then make them intersect.

---

[image]

Comment: Indeed very nice ! The intersection gives the points $B$ and $C$ and finally we get a convex quadrilateral only !

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume four points on a circle such that a pair of them are endpoints of a diameter and other vertices are on different part of semi circles.

These four points can determine infinitely many quadrilaterals which are not rectangles

Comment: Nice property for the rectangle triangles !